# C# custom object in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am relatively new to C# (WinForms), and had a question regarding combo boxes.  I have a combo box of Reviewer objects (it is a custom class with an overridden ToString method) and am currently attempting to go through all the checked items and use them to generate a setup file.

Here is how the combo box is populated (populated on form load).  Parameters is just a collection of linked lists and parsing code.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.GetUsers().Count; i++)
        {
            UserList.Items.Add(parameters.GetUsersArray()[i], parameters.GetUsersArray()[i].isSelected());
        }
```

Here is how I am trying to read it.  setup is a StringBuilder.  The problem is that GetID is not defined.  Does the add function above cast the Reviewer object to a Object object?  It looks a little funny since it creates a file fed into a Perl script.  A sample desired output line looks like this: inspector0 =>   "chg0306",

```
       for (int i = 0; i < UserList.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
       {
            setup.AppendLine("inspector" + i.ToString() + " => \t \"" +
                UserList.CheckedItems[i].GetID() + "\",");
       }
```

Here is the users class:  (Sample User is ID = aaa0000 name: Bob Joe)

```
public class Reviewer
{
    private string name;
    private string id;
    private bool selected;

    public Reviewer(string newName, string newID, bool newSelected)
    {
        name = newName;
        id = newID;
        selected = newSelected;
    }
    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        //string retVal = new string(' ', id.Length + name.Length + 1);
        string retVal = id + '\t' + name;
        return retVal;
    }
    public string GetID()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public bool isSelected()
    {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

For posterity, here is the Parameters class:

```
public class ParameterLists
{
    public ParameterLists()
    {
        projects = new LinkedList<string>();
        reviewers = new LinkedList<Reviewer>();
    }
    public enum FileContents {
        PROJECT_LIST,
        USERS_LIST,
    } 
    public LinkedList<Reviewer> GetUsers()
    {
        return reviewers;
    }
    public LinkedList<string> GetProjects()
    {
        return projects;
    }
    public Reviewer[] GetUsersArray()
    {
        Reviewer[] userArray = new Reviewer[reviewers.Count];
        reviewers.CopyTo(userArray, 0);
        return userArray;
    }
    public string[] GetProjectsArray()
    {
        String[] projectArray = new String[projects.Count];
        projects.CopyTo(projectArray, 0);
        return projectArray;
    }

    public void LoadParameters(string fileName)
    {
        //Reads the parameters from the input file.
    }
    private void CreateDefaultFile(string fileName)
    {
        // Create the file from the defaultfile , if it exists.
        // Otherwise create a blank default file.
    }

    private LinkedList <string> projects;
    private LinkedList <Reviewer> reviewers;
}
```

I am probably missing something simple, coming from embedded C++.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast that object:

```
((Reviewer)UserList.CheckedItems[i]).GetID()
```

Comment: I feel kinda dumb, but that appears to work.  That would appear to confirm my theory that it is storing it as an Object and not a Reviewer.  Thanks!